# Transformer Connectors for Temporary Service Panel

Tags: electrical-panel

I am installing a 100 AMP temporary construction service panel. The utility requires it to be within 5 ft. of the transformer pad.  The connectors run from the meter base into a 24" deep trench and then to within 24" of the pad.  (a) What wire size do I need for 100A - the utility is being coy and says it is the responsibility of the electrician (me), but my research says #2 AWG  (b) Do the cables need to run through conduit?

Comment: Is your panel a box-on-a-stick(4x4 post), or a pedestal with a cable-chase built into it (like a RV pedestal)?

Comment: Since it doesn't serve a residence, you'll need #1 aluminum.  However if your main breaker is smaller, you may get away with smaller wire.  Stay in aluminum.

Comment: My panel is a 100 temp service panel on a 4x4 post.  It has (2) 30A - 120V breakers and outlets and a 30A RV outlet.  It is meant only for power for saws, lights, etc,. during construction.   #2 AWG Aluminum seems to be the best choice.